# Can't create new Virtual Machine in VMWare Server using virtual disk created from VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmdk, vmware-server

I have 2 virtual machines I'm trying to convert from VirtualBox to VMWare server.  I exported the hard drives using the command

```
VBoxManage clonehd [uuid] OpenBSD.vmdk -format VMDK
```

This produced vmdk files that I put in the storage folder of VMWare server.  I configured machines with the same parameters, but get the following error on boot:

```
DetailsVMware Server unrecoverable error: (vmx)
ASSERT d:/build/ob/bora-203138/bora/devices/disk/disk.c:3868 bugNr=21838
A log file is available in "D:\vmachines\vmware\OpenBSD\vmware.log".  A core file is available in "D:\vmachines\vmware\OpenBSD\vmware-vmx-5852.dmp".  Please request support and include the contents of the log file and core file.  
To collect data to submit to VMware support, select Help > About and click "Collect Support Data". You can also run the "vm-support" script in the Workstation folder directly.
We will respond on the basis of your support entitlement.
```

I am having similar issues with a Ubuntu VM.  Both are headless machines with pretty simple hardware configurations.

Log file available at http://pastebin.com/rkZR3JDa

Any ideas?

Comment: Any chance you can paste a copy of that vmware.log file? May give some clues!

Comment: It was over 600 lines, so I put it on pastebin and linked to it

Answer (score 3):

All I can say is it looks like it isn't a valid VMDK file and it is causing VMware Server to crash.

After looking at that log file and a bit of creative Googling, I found other people who have come up with the [same problem](http://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/3021) - I cannot find a solution and it looks like this is a bug with VirtualBox.

I would personally try, if you have a machine with VMWare Workstation, using the Import tool and directly trying to convert the entire Virtual Box Virtual Machine.

Sorry I couldn't be more help.

Comment: This is the answer. I had the exact same problem. Converting with VBoxManage is causing some troubles and vmware server doens't like the converted machine. I converted the machine using vmware converter and it worked.